# How to control which background programs load for specific users in Window Server 2019?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, startup

I am still new to Windows Server maintenance so forgive my newbie question.

I have installed a translation program (Antidote) for one of my users on my Windows 2019 installation but it has 2 agents/programs that run in the background (similar to all the adobe programs that run when you install CC).  Now, these background agents load up for all my users as soon as they login, take up ram and also shows up in their system tray (which confuses some users and they are always trying to open it).

How can I make sure these background programs that are specific for one piece of software for one user only load up when they login?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to specify how they are launched.

Comment: I'm not sure other than I believe at startup as a background service. Not sure if that is what you were asking . Sorry!